# Cypress scrolling behaviour on `get` and relative positionning

Tags: material-ui, cypress

When calling Cypress `cy.get` method, the page is scrolled so that the selected element is at the top of the page.

This is problematic when there is a relatively positioned sticky toolbar on top of it, because it may systematically hide the element and thus fail the further `click` events.

This is reproducible with [Material UI "Dashboard" template](https://material-ui.com/getting-started/templates/) for instance.

Any idea how I could solve this, either by modifying the template to keep a sticky top menu without relative positionning (edit: actually the header is absolutely positionned), or setting up Cypress to slightly offset the scroll when getting elements?

Of course I can force clicks with `cy.click({force:true})` but that's not very good in the long run.

Answer (score 8):

This scrolling logic only applies to commands that are actionable above. We do not scroll elements into view when using DOM commands such as `cy.get()` or `.find()`.
Because of this

> disable scroll in the click command

```
.click({scrollBehavior:false})
```

Comment: Ah, thanks so much! I assumed it was the get that scrolled to, not the subsequent action.

Answer (score 2):

As you said, the page is scrolled so that the selected element is at the top of the page.

[Cypress docs:](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/interacting-with-elements.html#Scrolling)

> Before interacting with an element, we will always scroll it into view
> (including any of its parent containers). Even if the element was
> visible without scrolling, we perform the scrolling algorithm in order
> to reproduce the same behavior every time the command is run.

But you can get around this if it's causing problems with your test by adding {scrollBehavior:false} to the click command.

[Section of the docs](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration.html#Actionability)

Comment: No problem, I've revised the formatting. Still being checked. Thanks for contributing.

Comment: `center` seems appropriate, that's cool. This should be accepted.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `.pause()` method to see if `.get()` actually scroll the page. 
According to the documentation, page is never scrolled when using `.get()`, only when using action commands (like `.click() [source](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/interacting-with-elements.html#Scrolling)).

FYI there is a [feature request](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/871) to change the scrolling behaviour.

Also, there is a cheeky workaround you could use in every test:

```
Cypress.on('scrolled', $el => {
  $el.get(0).scrollIntoView({
    block: 'center',
    inline: 'center'
  });
});
```

Comment: Will check that but anyway it's the same problem is `click()` is responsible of the scroll :/ Interesting workaround thanks