# Cypress - Always focus element to a given offset from top of screen

Tags: javascript, cypress

When I run tests in Cypress, it always scrolls down to the element, so it is in the very top of the screen. But I'm writing tests for a WordPress system, where the fixed bar always is in the top of the screen taking up 75px (ish). So I can never see what's going on, when my test run.

Are there a way, where I can define *all* elements, for all tests, to so when they're in focus, that they are 200px from the top? Like a global constant?

**Code**

```
cy.get( 'tr[data-slug="cmb2"]' ).should( 'have.class', 'active' );
```

**See the problem here:**

[image: Cypress admin bar issues]

---

### Solution attempt 1: Set it in the `.env` configuration-file

It would be smart if I could set it in the `cypress.json`-file. I read the docs on [Cypress Configuration](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration.html#Global), but couldn't find it in there.

---

### Solution attempt 2: Hiding the admin-bar with CSS

I could also try and add a stylesheet to always load, when running Cypress-tests in the backend. But is this a normal way to get around it?

And even if I did this, I wouldn't know how to do this.

---

### Solution attempt 3: Use [scrollIntoView](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/scrollintoview)

I tried adding `scrollIntoView` with some options:

```
cy.get( 'tr[data-slug="cmb2"]' ).scrollIntoView({ offset: { top: 150, left: 0 } }).should( 'have.class', 'active' );
```

But I'm still unable to see the title of my div, when hovering it. I also tried [the solution suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61656878/1766219) that looks a bit like it.

---

### Solution attempt 4: Add [scrollBehavior](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration#Actionability) to my `.env`-file

I add that to my `.env`-file:

```
{
   "env": {
      "name": "staging",
      ...
   },
   "viewportWidth": 1100,
   "viewportHeight": 1800,
   "watchForFileChanges": false,
   "chromeWebSecurity": true,
   "scrollBehavior": "bottom"   <---- My attempt!
}
```

But no cigar:

[image: Scroll into view]

---

### Related questions

- [Cypress scrolling behaviour on `get` and relative positionning](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61654424/1766219)

Answer (score 8):

I'm not sure about your Wordpress site, but the following worked for the Material-UI site referenced in [Cypress scrolling behaviour on `get` and relative positionning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61654424/cypress-scrolling-behaviour-on-get-and-relative-positionning)

**.scrollIntoView() offset should be negative**

```js
it('make Elvis appear', () => {
  cy.viewport(750,480)
  cy.visit('https://mui.com/getting-started/templates/dashboard/');

  cy.contains('Elvis Presley').scrollIntoView({offset:{top: -100}})
})
```

**use native scrollIntoView**

```js
it('make Elvis appear', () => {
  cy.viewport(750,480)
  cy.visit('https://mui.com/getting-started/templates/dashboard/');

  // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView
  cy.contains('Elvis Presley')
    .then($el => $el[0].scrollIntoView(false)) // scrolls $el to bottom
})
```

**make header transparent**

```js
it('make Elvis appear', () => {
  cy.viewport(750,480)
  cy.visit('https://mui.com/getting-started/templates/dashboard/');

  cy.get('header').invoke('css', 'opacity', '0')
  cy.contains('Elvis Presley').scrollIntoView()
})
```

**using .scrollTo()**

This command applies to the scroll container, not the element you target, so the positioning may not come out correctly every time.

```js
function getScrollParent(node) {
  if (node == null) return null;

  if (node.scrollHeight > node.clientHeight) {
    return node;
  } else {
    return getScrollParent(node.parentNode);
  }
}

it('make Elvis appear', () => {
  cy.viewport(750,480)
  cy.visit('https://mui.com/getting-started/templates/dashboard/');

  cy.contains('Elvis Presley')
    .then($el => {
      const scrollParent = getScrollParent($el[0])
      cy.wrap(scrollParent).scrollTo('center')
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is a bug on this already reported [here](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/871). Cypress peeps fixed this [here](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/pull/8837). It needs to be merged though.

Comment: Thanks for this comment @voy. This should be the valid answer here as this is a bug/config and the options in answer above are prety much workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for element being hidden by website top menu on get(), contains(), click().

Add following to Cypress global config or test config.

From my cypress.config.ts (reduced to focus):

```
import { defineConfig } from 'cypress'

export default defineConfig({

  e2e: {
    scrollBehavior: false
  }
})
```

Then scroll "manually" using cy.scrollTo(), cy.scrollIntoView(), dynamically, ...

references:

- [Cypress configuration: Actionability](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration#Actionability)
- [StackOverflow: Disable Cypress from automatic scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67776142/disable-cypress-from-automatic-scrolling)