# Disable Cypress from automatic scrolling

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cypress

I am testing my application where I have very long side menu and I have a code like that:

```
cy.get('tab').click({force: true})
```

The automatic scroll happens between get and click and then selected tab is not visible since the top menu has possition fixed. I found many solutions but none of them worked. So far I tried `.click({force: true})` and `.click(scrollBehaviour: false})` also `.scrollIntoView()` between get and click.
Is there any other way to solve this issue?

Comment: can you share your html dom?

Answer (score 13):

You can set the `scrollBehavior` globally or per test(-suite).

I'm disabling it on a per tests basis like so:

```js
it('check something w/ autoscroll disabled', { scrollBehavior: false }, () => {
  cy.get('.tab').click();
  // do something else ...
});
```

Docs: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration#Actionability

Answer (score 4):

Did you try using `scrollBehaviour: 'top'` ?

You can find more details regarding the ScrollBehaviour here:

https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/interacting-with-elements#Scrolling
https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration#Actionability
https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/click#Arguments

Comment: scrollBehaviour seems to not working at all

Answer (score 4):

Did you try to type `"scrollBehavior": false` in cypress.json file? Because it worked for me.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31710655)

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how the auto-scroll is implemented, you can try adding this at the top of the test

```
cy.window().then(win => win.scrollTo = cy.stub())
```

which attempts to stub out the native `scrollTo` function. I haven't tried it, it may fail if `win.scrollTo` is read-only.

Here's the reference page [Window.scrollTo()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo), to can see in the notes some other variations to try if the app is using those instead.

Comment: I do not see any difference after applying it. It is still scrolling but actually even though the tab is sill not visible cypress clicks on the tab and it stops at that step. So it kinda helps, but no idea how and why it finally stops.

Comment: Without a reproducible example, it's just a stab in the dark. You could try setting the viewport large enough that there is no longer a need to scroll `cy.viewport(1500,1500)`.

Answer (score -1):

Based upon, 'Philip Kyeck's answer it works on specific commands as well. Like:

```
cy.get('SelectorHere').trigger("mouseenter", {scrollBehavior: false});
```